# How to add header ALSO to frontpage

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I have the following preamble which adds headers in right and left side (not sure how I would add one in center though) BUT it is missing on the front page... it is only from page 2 and on ward. Help

[image]

Comment: (1) A header is to inform where you are, and that  **must** be absolutely clear in the front page without the header, so what you want is a  bad idea.  (2) Do not post a screenshot with a chunk of code but a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, so we can reproduce the problem, make changes and test if that solve the problem.

Comment: That does like not even answer my question at all. The following preamble adds my name and assignment name to the top of every page but NOT the front page. I want to figure out how to do it ALSO to the front page. If you don't have any valueable information then why bother posting anything?

Comment: The above is only a comment, not an answer.  If I wanted to answer I would have done so where it says"Your answer". There are, however at least one valuable information in the comment, that is how to make properly  a question in this site, and I suggest again that you take it into account.